# Is there a way to export functions in C static library?

Tags: c, rust, interop, ffi

i am testing some C code in Rust, but rust only links to C static libraries on windows.

The problem is that the exported C functions are only exported to a Dynamic Library, and not to a Static one, since I can't use dlls in rust, i can't really link to the library with no exported symbols (if I try to, rust complains about unresolved references).

Some things I tried:

- Normal linking: these worked for a compilation one time, but I lost it, and since all the other normal ones go wrong.
- Static lib linked with Dynamic lib: sure, but it did not work, nor did the exported symbols appear in `dumpbin /exports`, or did the static lib rely on the dynamic lib.
- Static linked to Object linked to Dynamic: *what*

## Code:

### C:

```c
// Note this is compiled with CMake to generate both a DyLib and a Static Lib.

#define EXPORT __declspec (dllexport)

EXPORT int my_func (void) {
    return 3;
}
```

### Rust:

```rust
// build.rs:

fn main () {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=path/to/my/lib");
}

// lib.rs:

#[cfg (test)]
mod tests;

// No *-sys crate for simplicity
pub mod sys {
    #[link (name = "my_lib")] // since Windows msvc linking is based on static libs, no matter what it is going to search for a static lib anyway...
    extern {
        pub fn my_func () -> i32; // libc::c_int is an alias to i32 on my machine
    }
}

// tests.rs:

use crate::sys;

#[test]
fn my_func_works () {
    assert_eq!(3, unsafe { sys::my_func () });
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for editing it, the stackoverflow recommended the `c++` tag and i clicked it thinking that it was `c`

Comment: Static libraries "export" everything that is not declared `static`. So just dropping the `EXPORT` and writing simply `int my_func (void) { return 3; }` should work.

Comment: Sadly it don't work, the unresolved external symbol error appears, that is what led me to `__declspec (dllexport)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build script, you're telling cargo *where to look* for your library, but you never tell it to actually *use* the library. You need to add this to your `build.rs`:

```rust
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=native=my_lib.lib");
```

Note that the cargo docs have this to say about [`rustc-link-search`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-searchkindpath) (emphasis mine):

> The `rustc-link-search` instruction tells Cargo to pass the [`-L` flag](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html#option-l-search-path) to the compiler to add a **directory** to the library search path.

and about [`rustc-link-lib`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname):

> The `rustc-link-lib` instruction tells Cargo to **link the given library** using the compiler's [`-l` flag](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html#option-l-link-lib).

Comment: Doesn't `#[link (name = "my_lib")]` already does so?

Answer (score -2):

It is way out of scope for this answer, but this is why attributes and declspecs are such an anathema to making software work.

If you have a library; that library has some `names` which have a *global* scope.  For example, you could have a procedure called `ShaveMyBall` for grooming a football pre-game.  In a library, `ShaveMyBall` might just exist, but you might have some requirements about linking with externals, so that `ShaveMyBall` might need to be prefixed with `MyHairyBits_`.

This opposing requirements can readily be solved by symbol manipulation utiities rather than a grotesque infrastructure between programming languages.   A few simple object file manipulations can change `ShaveMyBall` into `MyHairyBits_ShaveMyBall`.

But, if you insist on using odd, poorly defined, and even worse, partially defined by a standards committe, you will end up with something that may work on occasion, which outside of setting you up for a microsoft buyout, is typically the death knell for any company.

Comment: Did not help much in this situation, but i'll consider it into making my future code better, so Thanks!